# Craft CMS v3.5.16 /admin/login 500 (Internal Error) occurs after site moved

Tags: control-panel, admin

Original site works fine. Moved site to new hosting (same domain name i.e. nutrano.com.au) via CPanel and now whilst /admin/login is accessible Invalid credentials show "Invalid username or password", whilst known valid/existing credentials generate the Console Error:

jquery.js:10099          POST https://nutrano.com.au/index.php?p=admin/actions/users/login 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:10099

I know after searching for 2 days that this is similar to several other issues none seem to reflect what I am seeing.

Please note: I am friend doing a friend a favour and have almost zero knowledge of Craft CMS (v3.5.16). Just trying to troubleshoot the problem. Thank you. Edward

Answer (score 2):

It would seem the website was trying to write sessions to /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70 (which is wrong and probably just missed after site transfer).
Once I modified it to use /tmp (where it should be) - Voila!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add on to this for any who run into similar problems. I was unable to find where that session variable was being called. I eventually noticed that in my web folder there were two files that had it.
One was .user.ini, the other was php.ini.

There was a reference to session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73” in .user.ini and php.ini in my web folder. Once I changed both of those to session.save_path = "/tmp" I was able to login.