# 500 Internal error on admin - session related

Tags: craft3, control-panel, admin, session, nitro

I am working on trying to get a local copy of a site working, but ran into an issue where the front end is working, but the admin page is not responding when I try to login.

This site is Craft 3.7.44 setup using Nitro on php 8.1 and MariaDB 10.6

In the browser console, I am seeing this error:
In Safari:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

In Firefox

> XHR POST http://exvgnt.nitro/index.php?p=admin/actions/users/login
> Blocked by DevTools

I was confused on the CORs type error and looked into the weblog and found the following error:

> 2022-06-19 19:36:18 [-][1][-][error][yii\web\Session::open] session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73)

I did a search through my project for any references to that session directory and found one in my .env file. Even after removing that I am seeing the same error.

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions? Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3):

I found it.

There were some files in my web folder that had the reference to `session.save` variable with that old path for php7.
Both `.user.ini` and `php.ini` had the following line:

```
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73”
```

Which I changed to

```
session.save_path = "/tmp”
```

This previous stackexchange post([Craft CMS v3.5.16 /admin/login 500 (Internal Error) occurs after site moved](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39065/craft-cms-v3-5-16-admin-login-500-internal-error-occurs-after-site-moved)), and a helpful comment from Pixel & Tonic's support staff about something overriding php.ini. That helped me zero in on the culprit!

Now I am able to log-in and continue the process of upgrading to Craft 4!